# alsa-base.conf non existent in etc/modprobe.d

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying to change my default audio device. However, alsa-base.conf just isn't in that folder. Is there any other way to do this?

I am running Raspbian.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create this file, make sure it is owned root, group root and set mode 0644 (owner read/write, group and other read). You can then add whatever `options` lines you want.  E.g.:

```
su root
cd /etc/modprobe.d
echo "options foo=bar" > alsa-base.conf
```

Should work, presuming you have a password set up for `root`.

Comment: Use `sudo -i` rather rthan `su` on Raspbian

Comment: @MNoit  Why?  As far as I'm aware, one is no more restrictive than the other.